# Number Long value from the document in mongoose toNumber not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Code is below

```
....
....

  for (i = 0; i < query.docs.length; i++) {
       
        query.docs[i].createdBy = query.docs[i].createdBy.toNumber();
    }

return query;
```

In the docs, createdBy is long, when I want to get number value from it, It doesn't work.I can't manipulate it returning value is same as if toNumber didn't work.

below is return value:

```
{
  "body": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "name": "XX",
        "description": "xx",        
        "createdBy": {
          "low": 0,
          "high": 0,
          "unsigned": false
        },
        "id": "63f0cce7515cdbf364c0fdfb"
      }     
    ]   
  },
  "header": {
    "isSuccess": true,
    "Code": 0
  }
}
```

I want to see createdBy as "createdBy": 0   ,

How can get the number value of it in my return .

edit: schema added.

```
const xSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        }
        createdBy: {
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Long,
            required: true,
            default: 0
        }       

    }   
);
```

Comment: Can you please add the definition of the schema you're trying to access? Also Mongoose & MongoDB version would be helpful.

Comment: In Mongoose v6.9.2 documentation (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html), I couldn't see any Long type. Is there any specific plugin you're using for that type?

Comment: Are you looking for `BigInt`? BigInts are stored as 64-bit integers in MongoDB (BSON type "long").